# How to understand this sentence about range, from the book Introduction to Computation and Programming Using Python

Tags: python, range

I am self learning Python via the book *Introduction to Computation and Programming Using Python*
and I'm stuck on this sentence in the book about range:

> If step is positive, the last element is the largest integer start + i*step less than stop.

I think I understand how range works: range(A, B, z) will start at A and try to "reach" B with a step size of z, and it B-1 will be the largest result if the step is 1. But I don't understand the sentence above by Prof. Guttag.

The last element will no doubt be the largest integer will  be the largest if the step is positive. But wouldn't the different between the last element and stop be (Stop - (Start + i*step))?

Why did he say that it will be **start + i*step less than stop.**?

Comment: "the largest integer, calculated as `start + i*step`, such that this number is less than `stop`."

Comment: This is just a parsing problem. The last element both: 1. satisfies the equation start + i * step; **and** 2. is less than stop. It is the largest such number.

Comment: Stop doesn't have to be an integer multiple of steps from start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are understanding it correctly. He doesn't mean that this is the quantity by which it is smaller than `stop`. He means that

- it is the largest integer
- that has the form `start + i*step`
- *and* is  *less than* (smaller than) `stop`

Comment: I get it now. Thanks a lot. I guess it's just the way the sentence was put.